# How to escape characters in dynamic fields with KQL

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

One of the inner values of my dynamic field contains "@".
How can I escape the @? (need to escape the "fields.@version")

```
let Source = datatable (fields: dynamic) [
    dynamic({"seq":17300,"@version":"1"})
];
Source | project fields, fields.seq //, fields.@version
```

Answer (score 2):

[Dynamic object accessors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/dynamic#dynamic-object-accessors)

A qualified string (single quote / double quote / triple back-tick) within brackets.

````
let Source = datatable (fields: dynamic) [
    dynamic({"seq":17300,"@version":"1"})
];
Source 
| project fields['@version'], fields["@version"], fields[```@version```]
````

| fields_@version | fields_@version1 | fields_@version2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dataexplorer.azure.com/clusters/help/databases/Samples?query=H4sIAAAAAAAAA8tJLVEIzi8tSk5VsFVISSwBwqScVAWNtMzUnJRiK4WUyrzE3MxkTYVoLgUggHI1qpWKUwuVrAzNjQ0MdJQcylKLijPz85SslAyVajW5Yq25oGZy1SgUFOVnpSaXKEBMjFaHKVaP1YGJIQxAiCUkJMBEgcxYAHiLfjyoAAAA)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
let Source = datatable (fields: dynamic) [
    dynamic({"seq":17300,"@version":"1"})
];
Source | project fields, fields.seq , fields.['@version']
```

Are there any other options?